# Why is my Laravel 5.7 session not working?

Tags: php, laravel, session, routes, config

I'm trying to get sessions to work in Laravel 5.7, but I can't seem to get it working; I'm not sure why. I've looked at the official docs, looked at a bunch of SO posts, done Googling for the issue on other sites, and I still can't figure it out.

Basically, I've got a route like the following in `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/some_path', 'SomeController@index');
```

Then, in the `index` method of `SomeController`, I have the following:

```
session(['test', 'Some Value']);
session(['test2', 'Some Other Value']);
session(['test3', 'Some Third Value']);
$value = session('test', 'Backup Value');
echo $value;
```

With that, I'm always getting `Backup Value` echoed to the screen.

If I go into `/storage/framework/sessions`, I see a session file that has the following content (which I have anonymized):

```
a:5:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"token-here";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:26:"http://example.com/some_path";}s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}i:0;s:5:"test3";i:1;s:16:"Some Third Value";}
```

Basically, it looks like the session is kind of working, but it only seems to store `test3`. If I comment out the `test3` line in the controller, then it only stores `test2`. And even if I only have the `test` line in the controller, it still doesn't retrieve the value.

I also tried switching the session to a DB session with the proper session migrate file a la https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session, but it's still not working.

Basically, I have no clue what's up. I can say that I'm not using the native Laravel auth, so I'm not sure if that matters, but I feel like it shouldn't. Also, I tried restarting my localhost, but that didn't make a difference and running both of the following commands, neither of which seem to change anything:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Lastly, I tried adding `use Session` at the top of the controller, but that doesn't seem to matter either.

Basically, I don't know what to do. What could possibly be causing this? Thank you.

Comment: You can use the session push method of Laravel.
e.g
`Session::push('test', 'some value');`

Comment: What happens if you put this first?

$value = session('test', 'Backup Value');

Comment: Deepak Singh, `Session::put()` and `Session::push()` work, but `session()` doesn't. Why? techcyclist, changing the order didn't make a difference. Also, part of my session file now looks like the following: `"test";i:1;s:10:"Some Value";s:4:"test";s:10:"Some Value";s:5:"test2";s:16:"Some Other Value";` Basically, it seems to be storing stuff from both `session()` and `Session::put()`, although the `session()` one can't be retrieved. I'm still so confused. What's Laravel doing under the hood to stop `session()` from working?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, it seems like the `Session` class only allows for the file method of saving sessions. I tried changing `SESSION_DRIVER` in `session.php` from `file` to `database`, but it's not saving in the DB; it's still saving to the file in the `storage` dir.

Comment: @HartleySan Updated with a answer. Check if that help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's happening here is that when you add this:

```
session(['test', 'x'])
```

It adds *test* at the **0th** index of the session and *x* at **1st**.
Now when you again do a

```
session(['test1', 'xx'])
```

It overwrites the **0th** and **1st** index of session with new values.
Therefore when you print the session data you get the last values.
You can check this by doing a `dd(session()->all())` and seeing the same on screen.
If you want to make a key value relation and store the data in such away, please use the syntax like this:

```
session(['test' => 'x']);
```

```
session(['test1' => 'xx']);
```

Comment: Okay, I officially feel stupid now. I was using the wrong syntax. Specifically, I was doing `session(['test', 'Some Value'])`, when I should have been doing `session(['test' => 'Some Value'])`. It's working now with the session file, which is good. However, when I switch the session driver over to `database`, even with the DB table there, it's still saving the session in the file. Any ideas?

Comment: This shouldn't happen if you have configure the session driver as db correctly. Make sure to check that your `SESSION_DRIVER` in .env file is set as database. Also check for session.php file. Lastly please run the two commands `php artisan config:clear and php artisan cache:clear` and logout and login again and check for entries in database.

Comment: Cripes! I finally got it to work, Deepak. I hadn't changed the `SESSION_DRIVER` value in the `.env` file. (I don't recall that being mentioned anywhere in the Laravel docs.) Anyway, that one change instantly made everything work. Thank you so much!

Comment: Cheers mate! :)

Answer (score 4):

those who are unable to save the session the issue is you guys are forgot to put the save() function after put given is the example.

```
$cartCount = Session::get('cartCount');
        if(empty($cartCount)){
            $cartCount = 0;
            Session::put('cartCount', $cartCount);
        }
        Session::save();
```

Answer (score 4):

Session::save() can be a life saver, definitely try that if still issues.

Comment: `session()->save();` solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

**Laravel 5.7 - store value in session with File system:**

Set the value in session:

```
session()->put('email', 'jai@gmail.com');
```

Get the value from session:

```
$email = session()->get('email');
```

Delete the session of email:

```
session()->forget('email');
```

It works like charm :)

Comment: @davefrassoni make sure you have included 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;' at the top of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason your code doesn't run through - eg you're using dd() somewhere, then your session will never save. This tripped me up for a good 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, all you need to do is add a "web" middleware chain function to your route rule.
 e.g

```
Route::get('/some_path', 'SomeController@index')->middleware('web');
```

Then clear cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```